# Appengine - Storing a Pickled in Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pickle

In Google Appengine, I'm interested in pickling an object and storing it in the datastore. I don't need to index it.

Is there any difference if I store it as a BlobProperty or TextProperty? Which one is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I just ran tests with both. It appears that you cannot use TextProperty with pickle. It will cause errors. Using it with BlobProperty, on the other hand, works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

**BlobProperty** can store *binary data* while **TextProperty** can store only *strings*.

You can use **BlobProperty** as TextProperty is basicly a BlobProperty with encoding.

Answer (score 2):

NDB now offers : [`PickleProperty`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#types).

> Value is a Python object (such as a list or a dict or a string) that is serializable using Python's pickle protocol; the Datastore stores the pickle serialization as a blob. Unindexed by default.
>
> Optional keyword argument: `compressed`.